# Current Password No Longer Matches Keyring

Tags: password

After changing the password, the prompt kept popping up: Current Password No Longer Matches Keyring. So I did a command in the terminal:

```
rm ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring
```

I know that this removed the old keyring.

I also know that it is responsible for security. So how to check that I have a new keyring with a new password? I just want the keyring to exist in my computer and I want to check it

Answer (score 3):

Next time you log in, simply verify whether the file `~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring` is there.

The keyring is automatically recreated if it is removed (just like it was automatically created the very first time you logged in).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't want to give up Linux, I liked POP OS. But I'm afraid of the consequences of removing the bunch of keys.